# Javascript results - not working properly

Tags: javascript, logic, dotnetnuke

This is using DotNetNuke with the XMod Pro module and a submission form.  I have a drop-down with two text fields.  Two of the options in the drop-down ("Additions" and "Classes") need to have their property classes entered as only a numeric option; the third drop-down option allows for alphanumeric property class.  The script is called on the submit button click.

In trying to get this working, I have ALERTS configured to show the values returned; see below.

```
Class Type: Additions / Property Class: BLD1 / Result: false
Class Type: Additions / Property Class: 2874 / Result: true

Class Type: Classes / Property Class: GAR / Result: false
Class Type: Classes / Property Class: 3484 / Result: true
```

The issue is that my "if / else if" logic is not working at all; I broke it out hoping to figure out what is causing the issue, but it defaults to the "ELSE" statement every time.  I have it configured for "return false" because I don't want the information submitted every time if the logic isn't work properly.

Any assistance would greatly be appreciated.  Thank you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function ValidateClass()
  {
    var ClassType = document.getElementById(PropertyClassAdd.DDL_ClassType);
    var ClassTypeValue = ClassType.value

    var PropertyClass = document.getElementById(PropertyClassAdd.txt_PropertyClass);
    var PropertyClassValue = PropertyClass.value

    var resultlogic = (/^[0-9]+$/.test(PropertyClassValue));

    if (ClassTypeValue == 'Additions' && resultlogic== 'false')
    {
      //alert("Please Enter a numeric value");
      alert("Additions - Class Type: "+ ClassTypeValue + " / Property Class: " + PropertyClassValue + " / Result: " + resultlogic);
      return false;
    }
    else if (ClassTypeValue == 'Classes' && resultlogic == 'false')
    {
      //alert("Please Enter a numeric value");
      alert("Classes - Class Type: "+ ClassTypeValue + " / Property Class: " + PropertyClassValue + " / Result: " + resultlogic);
      return false;
    }
    else if (ClassTypeValue == 'Additions' && resultlogic == 'true')
    {
      //alert("This Works");
      alert("Additions - Class Type: "+ ClassTypeValue + " / Property Class: " + PropertyClassValue + " / Result: " + resultlogic);
      return true;
    }
    else if (ClassTypeValue == 'Classes' && resultlogic == 'true')
    {
      //alert("This Works");
      alert("Classes - Class Type: "+ ClassTypeValue + " / Property Class: " + PropertyClassValue + " / Result: " + resultlogic);
      return true;
    }
    else
    {
      alert("ELSE - Class Type: "+ ClassTypeValue + " / Property Class: " + PropertyClassValue + " / Result: " + resultlogic);
      return false;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for looking at my code.  I figured it out; the resultlogic was a boolean bit answer.

So changing the code to look for "0" or "1" instead of "false" or "true" fixed the issue.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function ValidateClass()
  {
....    
    if (ClassTypeValue == 'Additions' && resultlogic == 0)
....
    else if (ClassTypeValue == 'Classes' && resultlogic == 0)
....
    else if (ClassTypeValue == 'Additions' && resultlogic == 1)
....
    else if (ClassTypeValue == 'Classes' && resultlogic == 1)
....
    else
....
  }
</script>
```